# Hibernate persists referenced entities without cascade=PERSIST

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have a table of children each of which can have a set of different toys. There is a table that stores the code of each available toy.

```
@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "child", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST )
    private Set<Toy> toys = new HashSet<>();

    // getters & setters
}

@Entity
public class ToyCode implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private int id;

    // getters & setters
}

@Entity
public class Toy implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ToyPK id = new ToyPK();

    @MapsId( "childId" )
    @ManyToOne
    private Child child;

    @MapsId( "toyId" )
    @ManyToOne  // <-- there is no cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST
    private ToyCode toyCode;

    // getters & setters
}
```

Although the toyCode member of Toy class has non cascading attribute Hibernate persists it.

```
Child elena = new Child();
Toy barbie = new Toy();
barbie.setChild( elena );
barbie.getId().setChildId( elena.getId() );
barbie.getId().setToyId( 4218 );
barbie.setToyCode( new ToyCode( 4218 ) );
elena.addToy( barbie );
em.persist(elena);
```

I've no 4218 record in ToyCode table but Hibernate creates it.

Am I wrong? Is this the right behavior or I should file a bug? If it is correct how can I prevent Hibernate to save new toy codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the intended behavior. When you map an entity with `@MapsId` you get the cascade PERSIST too. It seems logic to me as the `@MapsId("toyId")` needs to point to a an existing entity with that primary key value.

See this JIRA issue: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4858

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It does not seem so logic to me since I don't have any way to remove cascading. In my case ToyCode is a table of all available values, first I provide all toy codes and after I can use them. Sure I can find a way to prevent auto persisting but it seems odd to me. Moreover I tried it with eclipselink and it works as I expected.

Comment: If you first save the toy codes and after you use them, then should be no problem. But your example looks different: the toy code does not exist, but you want to set it to a toy.

Comment: It's an example. I could have a method that get a ToyCode as a parameter so I don't know if it is new or not. Thanks again.